# Hive query hangs just after "kill command" prompt

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I've done many restarts and there are no error messages. Basic commands like

```
show databases;
```

work ok. But the problem occurs when I run something that requires a map or reduce process like this:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/chicago_bus.tsv' SELECT * from test.chicago_bus
    > ;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = vaughn_20170728153344_1e2d571c-920d-49de-8ddf-f57b6d0655d5
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1501270163820_0001, Tracking URL = http://vaughn-notebook:8088/proxy/application_1501270163820_0001/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1501270163820_0001
```

I ran the "hadoop job -list" command and got the following, if it helps:

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.

17/07/28 16:02:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/07/28 16:02:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Total jobs:1
                  JobId      State       StartTime      UserName           Queue      Priority   UsedContainers  RsvdContainers  UsedMem     RsvdMem     NeededMem     AM info
 job_1501270163820_0001       PREP   1501270430437        vaughn     root.vaughn        NORMAL                0               0       0M          0M            0M  http://vaughn-notebook:8088/proxy/application_1501270163820_0001/
```

I've heard that the way memory handling is configured in yarn can have an effect, but am not sure what the right setup is for my configuration. I'm on a laptop with 16GB of memory. I've posted the hive.log, mapred-site.xml, and yarn-site.xml at:

http://vaughn-s.net/hadoop

I've tried looking for the M/R job logs, but I'm not sure where to find them. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to have a look at Resource Manager UI? typically present at port 8088.
So, on a browser going to domain.name:8088/cluster/apps/RUNNING show show you more.

In your case http://vaughn-notebook:8088/proxy/application_1501270163820_0001/

or on the command line, type 
yarn log -applicationId 1501270163820_0001 >> ~/1501270163820_0001.log

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I see for that job in the Resource Manager: http://imgur.com/7r6lzqR

Comment: Yes, you may click on logs (right bottom corner) hyperlink and explore more about it.

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that the job isn't receiving a tracking UI. From what I've been able to search on, this means that yarn isn't getting the resources it needs. However, I've configured yarn-site.xml to allocate a reasonable amount of memory. I'm not sure what else could be doing it.